# how can i place an object(imageview) on a specific background portion and make it run on different android devices?

Tags: android

i have a background. In that a component is drawn. Not centrally, suppose a box but not at exact center.I want to place another object  may be an imageview. Exact on top of that box drawn in background. 
i somehow managed to set it on my  tablet device. But its not working on other tablets.any good idea?

I have tried using getting screen width height, but the box drawn is not exact matching..even statically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make different layouts for different size of devices and resolution.Otherwise it will get distorted for other devices.For more see this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

use xml with bitmap:

```
<bitmap gravity="center_horizontal|top" android:tileMode="disable" android:src="@drawable/YOUR_DRAWABLE" />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap